# Jsoup.connect(url) Dejó de funcionar

Tags: android, jsoup

El siguiente fragmento de codigo habia estado funcionando correctamente por dos meses (está en un async task), no lo habia tocado(hasta hoy que dejó de funcionar). La url está vigente y puedo acceder tanto desde mi pc como desde el navegador web del celular.

```
String url2 ="https://criptonoticias.com/colecciones/feliz-cumpleanos-2do-aniversario-lanzamiento-ethereum/#axzz4oMiSt119";
        //String  documentoProcesado = "";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url2).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                    .timeout(60000).get();
            Element primerDiv = doc.getElementById("et-recent-posts-3");//ERROR
            //String claseBuscar;
            int density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
            //for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
                //claseBuscar = String.valueOf(i);
            Elements articulos = primerDiv.getElementsByClass("widget_list");
            Elements ar = articulos.select("li");
            for (Element articulo : ar){
                    //El selector span:nth-child(x) busca al padre de span y elige al elemento hijo en la posición x
                direccion = articulo.getElementsByTag("a").attr("href");
                String direccionImagen = articulo.getElementsByTag("img").attr("src");
                String titulo = articulo.getElementsByTag("a").attr("title");
                String fecha = articulo.getElementsByClass("updated").text();
                inicializarData(direccionImagen, titulo, fecha, density);
            }
            //}

        }
```

El logcat me tira el NullPointerExcepion en:

```
Element primerDiv = doc.getElementById("et-recent-posts-3");
```

ya chequé y ese "id" sigue vigente asi como las demas etiquetas de busqueda que uso. El error que me da es este:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mal.saul.preciosbitcoinmexico.Fragment.FragmentNoticias$ConsultaAsyn.consulta(FragmentNoticias.java:146)
at com.mal.saul.preciosbitcoinmexico.Fragment.FragmentNoticias$ConsultaAsyn.doInBackground(FragmentNoticias.java:105
at com.mal.saul.preciosbitcoinmexico.Fragment.FragmentNoticias$ConsultaAsyn.doInBackground(FragmentNoticias.java:89)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

La instruccion que menciones puede dar null por las siguientes razones:

1. No consigue el elemento con id "et-recent-posts-3".
2. la variable doc es nula.

como dices que siguen teniendo los mismos id yo me inclinaria a que algo esta pasando al obtener el doc y viendo q es la primera instruccion que utilizas creo estar seguro que el problema es alli.

Puedes probar lo siguiente para verificar.

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url2).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                .timeout(60000).get();
    if(doc==null)
     {
    Log.e("prueba","doc es null");
     }
```

y luego chequea tu logcat , tambien puedes hacer un simple debug.

Comment: ya hice el debug y me dio que doc: <!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" lang="es">
<![endif]--> y aun ahi mas... y primerDiv = null.

Comment: estuve leyendo el valor de doc y al parecer no me esta jalando la pagina completa por eso no localiza al id et-recent-posts-3. alguna solucion a esto?

Comment: ya lo arreglé. aunque la respuesta no me satisface del todo, agregué esto a la solicitu que hace el doc: .maxBodySize(0)

Comment: perfecto , me alegra poder haber ayudado , saludos.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, sabes otra forma de lograrlo, la idea de bajarme toda la pagina no me gusta